# Полное закрытие программы

Tags: macos, mac

Как закрыть приложение? При нажатии на крестик он просто уходит, но не закрывается. А нажав по иконке приложения, которая отображается в Dock, оно уже не открывается, значит уже удалилось из памяти. И закрыть его можно только ПКМ->"Завершить". Как сделать, чтобы оно закрывалось целиком по нажатию на крестик?

Comment: Закрыть приложение можно комбинацией Cmd + Q!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю вопрос все таки не связан с программированием, это вопрос о том как закрываются приложения в Mac OS. Действительно, большинство приложений не закрываются нажатием на крестик (но есть и исключения, такие как app store). Вы правы, приложения полностью не закрываются нажатием на крестик, нужно выполнить либо этот правый щелчок, и нажать завершить, либо находясь в самом приложении, нажать на верхнем баре название приложения, и выбрать последний пункт "Завершить приложение" ("Quit App"), тогда оно полностью закроется, и при этом если оно не закреплено в Dock, то оно от туда вообще исчезнет, либо же если оно закреплено, пропадет маленький кружочек под иконкой. Я надеюсь, что я правильно ответил на Ваш вопрос, потому что теги не те стоят, если же нет, то скажите, я удалю вопрос.

Comment: Вообще вы правильно меня поняли. И ответили на один вопрос, про закрытие. Но образовался другой вопрос. При нажатии на крестик приложение оно закрывает лишь окно, а в Dock оно остается с кругляшом под ним. Нажимая по этой иконки окно не открывается снова, как сделать чтоб оно начало открываться? Или разворачиваться ?

Comment: @JoMax скорее всего это зависит от программы, ну а вообще, достаточно левого щелчка, и программа опять запустится.

Comment: Илья Терезников, Я думал также. Может быть где-то я пропустил галочку. У меня не открывается((( Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

В терминале пишем sudo killall название приложения